# VBA Excel - Merged Cell + Single Cell (both contain numbers, I want a sum of them)

Tags: vba, excel, sum

Cells O2:P2 are merged and contain 28/12/2016

Cell R2 contains the formula '=O2+13' which ends up as 10/01/2017

This is a 14 day period from 28/12/16 - 10/01/17.

I need O2:P2 from the ACTIVE sheet and +14 to it in DD/MM/YYYY format then paste it back into O2:P2

```
Sub AllInOne()

' Create New Sheet
ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Name = "RenameMe"

' Carry Flex
ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value = ActiveSheet.Previous.Range("R24").Value

' New Datestamp

' Clear New Timesheet
ActiveSheet.Range("E12:R19").ClearContents
ActiveSheet.Range("E26:F26,I26:M26,P26:R26").ClearContents
ActiveSheet.Range("E27:F27,I27:M27,P27:R27").ClearContents
ActiveSheet.Range("E12").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `DateAdd` function, with selecting "d" (days), as the interval parameter to add.

Since your Range("O2:P2") is merged, then use O2 as the reference range.

```
Range("O2").Value = DateAdd("d", 14, Range("O2").Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If its merged, use only O2 instead of o2:p2, it should work

Comment: WorksheetFunction.Sum (O2 + 14)

I have this at the moment, how would I write it to now put that sum into O2:P2?

Comment: @Bailey - `Activesheet.Range("O2").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("O2").Value + 14`